# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando implementar uma pilha(banco de dados),o problema é que eu nao estou conseguindo enviar os meus dados para as outras Activitys do meu aplicativo,por isso quando eu abro outra activity para verificar se os dados estão lá,ela da um erro de nullPointerExepetion,eu ja tentei mandar a pilha por referência para a outra a activity,porém o programa da erro do mesmo jeito,alguém pode me ajudar?Eu quero poder acessar os dados da minha pilha independente da Activity que eu esteja(sem que eles sejam apagados)

**Main**

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn;
    private EditText texto;
    public BancodeDados DB = new BancodeDados();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        texto.setText("Insira um dado");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String y = texto.getText().toString();
                DB.InserirDado(y);
                pagina2 receber = new pagina2();
                receber.recebe(DB);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Enviado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        Intent i = null;

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mnTela1:
                i = new Intent(this, pagina2.class);
                Toast.makeText(this, "item1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.mnTela2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "item2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Activity Secundária**

```
public class pagina2 extends AppCompatActivity{
    private EditText data;
    private Button btn;
    BancodeDados DataBase = new BancodeDados();

    public void recebe(BancodeDados DB){
        DataBase = DB;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagina2);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Data);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    data.setText(DataBase.removeDado());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Pilha(BancodeDados)**

```
public class BancodeDados {
    elemento primeiro;
    elemento ultimo;

    public void InserirDado(String x) {
        elemento novodadoinicio = new elemento();
        novodadoinicio.dado = x;
        novodadoinicio.proximo = primeiro;
        if(primeiro==null){
            ultimo = novodadoinicio;
        }
        primeiro = novodadoinicio;
    }

    public void InsereFinal(String x){
        elemento novodadoultimo = new elemento();
        novodadoultimo.dado = x;
        novodadoultimo.proximo = primeiro;
        if(ultimo==null){
            primeiro = novodadoultimo;
        }
        ultimo = novodadoultimo;
    }

    public String removeDado(){
        String x;
        x = primeiro.dado;
        primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
        return x;
    }
}
```

log do Android

```
03-28 01:05:01.431 20564-20564/com.project.meuapp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.project.meuapp2, PID: 20564
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.project.meuapp2.elemento.dado' on a null object reference
 at com.project.meuapp2.BancodeDados.removeDado(BancodeDados.java:43)
 at com.project.meuapp2.pagina2$1.onClick(pagina2.java:30)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Nota:Ja tentei criar um arquivo tipo texto numa pasta dentro do projeto android,porém quando eu chamo as funções java para criar um arquivo e ler o arquivo,ele não lê muito menos cria,e o log do Android não acusa nenhum erro

Comment: ReZ, não precisa da tag java, android é java, está subtendido.

Comment: foi mal :S.....

Comment: (String x;) está errado essa declaração, ou você declara  (String x = alguma) coisa
ou você faz um (new StringBuilder();) concatenando o dado.

Answer (score 6):

O Erro mostra o seguinte :

> ```
> to read from field 'java.lang.String com.project.meuapp2.elemento.dado' on a null object reference
> ```

Quer dizer, que um objeto está nulo! 
Seguindo o stack, o  erro ocorre quando há o click na `pagina2`, quando chama o `BancodeDados.removeDado`

> ```
>  at com.project.meuapp2.BancodeDados.removeDado(BancodeDados.java:43)
>  at com.project.meuapp2.pagina2$1.onClick(pagina2.java:30)
> ```

```
 public String removeDado(){
        String x;
        x = primeiro.dado;
        primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
        return x;
    }
```

Quando você chama este método o objeto `primeiro` ele está nulo! 
É necessário instancia-lo antes de chamar sua propriedade propriedade!

Answer (score 2):

Para passar as informações de uma activity pra outra, o que você deve fazer é adicionar informações ao intent que abre aquela activity.

Isso pode ser alcançado com o método intent.putExtra(TAG, informacao). Segue exempo:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, pagina2.class);
    String mensagem = "Olá Mundo!";
    intent.putExtra("MINHA_MENSAGEM", message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Na activity que recebe a informação, você deve acessar essas informações no método getIntent().getExtras(), que retorna um Bundle (mapa que contém as informações enviadas no intent). Segue exemplo:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mensagem = intent.getStringExtra("MINHA_MENSAGEM");
```

OBS: Para enviar um objeto é necessário enviá-lo como um parcelable ou um serializable. Uma biblioteca útil para atingir esse resultado é a disponível em https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler